# How to stop Smart Card window when using SunMSCAPI Provider

Tags: java

how to get certificate chain from MS Store without showing pop up window for the smart card like this one:

[image]

I don't need the private keys, I just need the public certificates in the store.

I use

```
KeyStore msCertStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
msCertStore.load(null, null);
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution to this annoying problem yet? lol